# How to retrieve data from a page in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I want to check what data is held by a SQL Server page. I have the page id, file id number.

Is there any way to check what data it holds by the page.

- Page id: 6908648
- File id : 1

Comment: Did you search for anything? [Anything at all?](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00rgmLp6atr-mMsfW20fJcueU-ptA%3A1593044917152&ei=te_zXqrqCOSm_Qbks5LoDA&q=how+to+see+the+data+on+a+page+sql+server&oq=how+to+see+the+data+on+a+page+sql+server&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECCMQJzoECCEQClD6CVjNDGDkFmgAcAB4AIABUIgB1wKSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjqmJfj2pvqAhVkU98KHeSZBM0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Comment: why do you add the tag "azure"? Are you using Azure SQL database?

Comment: Hi Leon, Yes I am using Azure SQL Database

Answer (score 1):

You can use DBCC PAGE to get that. But, these are undocumented procedure. So, it might not work always and don't use it in a production code.

[Read more on DBCC PAGE usage](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1578/using-dbcc-page-to-examine-sql-server-table-and-index-data/)

Also, read Paul Randal excellent blog post : https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/

> DBCC PAGE ( ['database name'|database id], -- can be the actual name
> or id of the database file number, -- the file number where the page
> is found page number, -- the page number within the file print option
> = [0|1|2|3] -- display option; each option provides differing levels of information )

```sql
DBCC TRACEON(3604) -- trace flag Should be set to get DBCC Page output to console
DBCC PAGE(DB_ID(),1,6908648,3) WITH TABLERESULTS -- option 3: for both header, data
 GO
```